# Geocoordinates/Lines - How can i calculate what is near to a point

Tags: geolocation

I have set up a database which have Nodes with Latitude and Longitude, i connect the Nodes with edges which contains additional informations.
(2 Tables in a MsSql server tNodes and tEdges)

Now i want to search what is "near" to a point, for exmaple:

[image]

There are 2 Edges near the Star, and i want to fetch them.
Does anybody know a really fast approach to do this?

Comment: This is the perpendicular distance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_distance (For comparing distances you don't need to do the sqrt bit.)

Comment: Could you add info about your technology stack? Which version of sql server are you using? Sql server 2008 has support for spatial data types. Is it an option for you to use those? What is your need for precision? Are you in searching within a specific perimeter or how is "near" defined?